# How do you put the magnifying glass and "search" in the search input box, like in StackOverflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assuming it is possible with just CSS, but wanted to know if someone could share the code.

Guessing the magnifying glass is a background image, but need JavaScript to remove "search" on focus.

Also, how do you get it to submit when hitting "return" rather than needing a "search" submit button?

Comment: did you attempt anything first ?

Answer (score 20):

There are multiple elements involved.

Use Chrome DevTools (F12) to inspect these things.

Comment: Note that today you should use the `input[type="search"]` element, with the `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

few questions there:

1. Submit on return, if you put an input in a form, and have focus on said input, when you press enter the browser will by default submit the form.
2. Text masking. you can do this easily in jquery or any other framework. essentially you will remove the text "search" on focus, but only that text so if there was something like "foo" it would not replace it.

for your text masking needs: [text mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new `input` types for that.

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" results="0" />
```

The 'results' attribute will add the magnifying glass icon in WebKit browsers.

UPDATE: No longer working in FF, Chrome, or Edge in 2021.

Comment: MDN says (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) that type="search" is only supported by IE 10+

Comment: This feature was deprecated in Chrome, due to it not catching on in other browsers. See: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5738199536107520

Comment: Looks like there is pretty good support now:  https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-search

Answer (score 0):

```html
USE THIS: <input type="image" src="/_i/mag.png" alt="Search">

EXAMPLE CODE:
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input type="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z'></path></svg>" alt="Search">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is recommended that you provide an explanation of your solution.

Comment: Your snippet is broken.

Answer (score -6):

View -> Page source.

Seriously, it's all there.

Comment: Irrelevant answer, this is not helpful at all

Comment: @franko_camron why this answer is considered irrelevant, and at the same time [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/711526/1429387) given 2 minutes later, which in fact suggests a similar solution, gains 20 points and becomes the most upvoted one?

Comment: @naXa Simply because a link can be broken and answers are supposed to be helpful to other people searching for the same answer. If you want to suggest that the person is not trying hard enough, nothing wrong with this but then use the comments, don't make it an "answer" and expect people to upvote it. Maybe other people have only spent a few minutes but they have tried to provide something useful as opposed to pointing the blame and disguise it as an answer. Also don't forget that some people are beginners and may not know how to inspect a page yet, or decipher a lot of code.

Comment: @Mig what "link"? neither this, nor referred answer have external links. This answer has +16 upvotes and -19 downvotes. which makes it the most contradictory answer in this thread. So you are saying that the answer is rude, and it's the main reason why it's downvoted? ok, I see your point... agree. but I don't think it makes the answer "irrelevant answer, not helpful at all"  (as franko says). I strongly disagree with franko. the answer is helpful to junior web devs who may not yet realize that a lot of knowledge can be gained from analyzing existing pages sources (for free!)

Comment: @naXa precisely. I made a general comment, this case is even worse because there is no link at all. I agree with you that reading code is good to learn even if sometimes hard. But you have to put yourself in the skin of somebody looking for the same answer. They don’t have the code at all, so what is the point?  Please do not take my comment personally. For me stackoverflow is a place to get answers primarily. Gaining reputation via points is secondary. Like I said in my opinion this answer is not worthless but should just be a comment because it is not helpful. Then people can still upvote it

Comment: This answer is not helpful People in SO expect usable code as an answer,  Not a link to an answer nor the name of a tool that can be used to gather information in order to write their own answer. -1